# how to use gdb.lookup_type find local type definition

Tags: python, c, struct, gdb

I have a C static function, and a struct type is defined in it. It may look like:

```
static void do_stuff(parameters...) {
    struct example {
        uint32_t a;
        uint32_t b;
    };
}
```

I tried to use python gdb module to find this type - gdb.lookup_type('struct example'), but I got an error saying that the type is not defined. If I moved this struct definition outside of this static function, then everything would be good. I guess I need to specify the block parameter in the lookup_type function. I tried gdb.selected_frame().block() (and its superblock, static_block, global_block), but it doesn't work for me. I am new to python and gdb module, so I am not sure why a local struct type cannot be found here, even if I passed the local block to lookup_type. Can anyone give me some help about this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution by myself, though I am not sure if it is the best one.

I tried to check all symbols in the current frame's block, and I found that the local struct definition can be found in it. The code may look like:

```
for symbol in gdb.selected_frame().block():
    if symbol.type.tag == 'example' and symbol.type.code = gdb.TYPE_CODE_STRUCT:
        # do something
```

Hope this is useful for someone who has the same problem with me.